# How to use custom font in gmail?

Tags: html, css, fonts, gmail, webfonts

How can we use custom fonts in mailer especially gmail. I have searched a lot but haven't found anything useful but I saw one "uxpin" mailer using "proxima nova" font in my gmail account....will greatly appreciate any help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<![endif]-->
<title>Virgin Atlantic</title>

<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {font-family: 'GothamLight';    src: url('http://ravisharma.ml/mailer1/fonts/GothamLight.eot');    src: url('http://ravisharma.ml/mailer1/fonts/GothamLight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),         url('http://ravisharma.ml/mailer1/fonts/GothamLight.woff') format('woff'),         url('http://ravisharma.ml/mailer1/fonts/GothamLight.ttf') format('truetype'),         url('http://ravisharma.ml/mailer1/fonts/GothamLight.svg#GothamLight') format('svg');    font-weight: normal;    font-style: normal;}
    @media screen{
  body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif !important;
  }
}

}   @media screen and (max-width: 639px){
        #main_table{
            width:100% !important;
            display:block;
        }

}   @media screen and (max-width: 639px){
        h1{
            font-size:20px !important;
        }

}   @media screen and (max-width: 639px){
        h2{
            font-size:14px !important;
        }

}   @media screen and (max-width: 639px){
        p{
            font-size:10px !important;
        }

}   @media screen and (max-width: 639px){
        h3{
            font-size:14px !important;
        }

}

</style>

</head>

<body style="margin: 0;padding: 0;">
    <table id="main_table" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border-spacing="0" style="width: 640px;border-collapse: collapse;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;">
        <tr>
            <td class="td_50" style="width: 50%;">
                <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;color: #b24761;"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/eb9c4a4284960321518684c4d/images/432620e4-25dc-4f16-a784-9f67b629e72a.jpg" alt="virgin atlantic" style="width: 100%;float: left;display: block;margin: 0 auto;"></a>
            </td><!--title ends-->

            <td class="td_50" style="width: 50%;">
                <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;color: #b24761;"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/eb9c4a4284960321518684c4d/images/cd675339-2051-4c40-b4c2-0101af8dbda4.jpg" alt="virgin atlantic" style="width: 100%;float: left;display: block;margin: 0 auto;"></a>
            </td><!--title ends-->
        </tr><!--table row 1 ends-->

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="td_100" style="width: 100%;">
                <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/eb9c4a4284960321518684c4d/images/e714b3ca-2b83-4241-8e81-bda71a259254.jpg" alt="virgin atlantic" style="width: 100%;float: left;display: block;margin: 0 auto;">
            </td><!--title ends-->

        </tr><!--table row 1 ends-->

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="content td_100" style="width: 100%;padding: 20px;background: #fff;">
                <h1 style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; 'Margin:0;padding: 10px 0 25px 0;width: 100%;float: left;font-size: 25.5px;">BUSINESS IS AN ADVENTURE MAKE IT EPIC.</h1>
                <h2 style="Margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%;float: left;font-size: 16px;color: #111;line-height: 24px;">Are you heading London or US anytime soon? We have everything you expect in business, but in Premium Economy</h2>
                <ul style="Margin: 0 ;padding: 0;width: 100%;float: left;padding-top: 20px;">
                    <li style="width: 100%;float: left;list-style: none; Margin:0; padding:8px 0; line-height:normal;"><p class="p1" align="left" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0; width: 3%;float: left; line-height:normal;">- </p><p class="p2" align="left" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 97%;float: left; line-height:normal;">Speed through the airport thanks to special priority checkin, bag drop and boarding.</p></li>
                    <li style="width: 100%;float: left;list-style: none; Margin:0; padding:8px 0; line-height:normal;"><p class="p1" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 3%;float: left; line-height:normal;">- </p><p class="p2" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 97%;float: left; line-height:normal;">Extra baggage allowance of 3 cases upto 23kg each..</p></li>
                    <li style="width: 100%;float: left;list-style: none; Margin:0; padding:8px 0; line-height:normal;"><p class="p1" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 3%;float: left; line-height:normal;">- </p><p class="p2" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 97%;float: left; line-height:normal;">Recline on your luxurious wide leather seat with headrest one of the biggest in its class.</p></li>
                    <li style="width: 100%;float: left;list-style: none; Margin:0; padding:8px 0; line-height:normal;"><p class="p1" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 3%;float: left; line-height:normal;">- </p><p class="p2" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 97%;float: left; line-height:normal;">Relax preflight with glass of welcome bubbly and newspaper in our dedicated cabin.</p></li>
                    <li style="width: 100%;float: left;list-style: none; Margin:0; padding:8px 0; line-height:normal;"><p class="p1" align="left" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 3%;float: left; line-height:normal;">- </p><p class="p2" align="left" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 97%;float: left; line-height:normal;">Enjoy your choice of three delicious main dishes including a vegetarian option, upgraded with china crockery,                   
                    cutlery and linen.</p></li>
                    <li style="width: 100%;float: left;list-style: none; Margin:0; padding:8px 0; line-height:normal;"><p class="p1" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 3%;float: left; line-height:normal;">- </p><p class="p2" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 97%;float: left; line-height:normal;">Snooze or freshen up on night flights with your Relax Pack.</p></li>
                    <li style="width: 100%;float: left;list-style: none; Margin:0; padding:8px 0; line-height:normal;"><p class="p1" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 3%;float: left; line-height:normal;">- </p><p class="p2" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 97%;float: left; line-height:normal;">Stay connected with inseat power and onboard WIFI.</p></li>
                    <li style="width: 100%;float: left;list-style: none; Margin:0; padding:8px 0; line-height:normal;"><p class="p1" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 3%;float: left; line-height:normal;">- </p><p class="p2" style="display: inline;font-size: 13px;color: #111;Margin:0;width: 97%;float: left; line-height:normal;">Help yourself to tempting snacks or stretch your leg at our social space called Wander Wall.</p></li>
                </ul>

                <h3 style="width: 100%;float: left; Margin:0; padding-top: 35px;color: #111;font-size: 16px;">Book now on <a href="http://www.virgin-atlantic.com/us/en.html" style="text-decoration: none;color: #b24761;">www.virginatlantic.com</a></h3>
            </td><!--title ends-->

        </tr><!--table row 1 ends-->
    </table><!--table ends-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for. Do you want to customize your own Gmail interface? Or do you want to send mail to Gmail accounts with custom fonts? Does this have anything to do with programming?

Comment: Yes, I want to send mail to gmail users with custom fonts.

Answer (score 12):

Gmail does not support `@font-face` or custom web font.

The safe fonts that are supported by gmail and most webmail clients are:

- Arial
- Century Gothic
- Courier New
- Garamond
- Georgia
- Helvetica
- Impact
- Lucida
- Times New Roman
- Tahoma
- Trebuchet
- Verdana

You should choose the above font to support most webmail clients, otherwise it will return as the default font.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use it the way they are used in normal web pages. So first you just include your hosted webfonts in the `<head>` of your document:

```
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

There could be problems with Outlook so you could make loading the font conditional for Outlook like this:

```
<head>
  <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Then you just normally set your font in CSS:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: ‘Open Sans’, Arial, sans-serif !important; // Arial will be used as a fallback, in Outlook for example
}
```

Or inline:

```
<p style="font-family: ‘Open Sans’, Arial, sans-serif;">Open Sans text</p>
```

Comment: I have tried everything you suggested but its still not working and using arial....I'm using mailchimp to send emails.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with MailChimp other than the name. Could you try it like this: https://ericlbarnes.com/2015/03/06/mailchimp-fonts/

Comment: I have noticed that if I add 'Open Sans' to font-family from 'inpect element' panel it works but by default its not there although i have added in the inline css like above...I think gmail is removing 'Open Sans' from font-family property for some reason and fonts are working well in mailchimp

Comment: Oh my bad. I just read that Gmail doesn't actually support web fonts. You can read more about web font support here: https://litmus.com/blog/typography-tips-for-email-designers

Comment: Yeah, when I read that I thought so too but when I saw 'uxpin' mailer using custom font in gmail, I thought that there have to be some way  to do so...thats why all this fiasco.

Comment: if you can give me a mail id then I could forward you that mailer

Comment: Are you sure they didn't use images to display the font? Or maybe you have it loaded in your computer or something? I'm really not sure.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't reply earlier....Yes, I'm pretty sure that it wasn't an image as I could select that text and I don't have that font in my desktop.

Comment: Okey, maybe they send the fonts as an attachment or something (don't know how that would work). Or Proxima Nova is some kind of special font that even Gmail wants to display. Have you tried setting a class like `.myFont { font-family: Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif; }` and then set the class to a td like this `<td class="myFont">Text</td>`?

Comment: Yes, I tried something like that and it didn't worked...anyway I'll look forward to some other ways to do it..

Comment: Hey @RaviSharma Did you manage to make it work ? I'm also having problems here : it works fine on mobile but not on desktop gmail :S (OpenSans)

Comment: yes, it can work but not with 'mailchimp'. After adding fonts I had to manually select all the email markup (Ctrl+A) from the browser window then paste to my compose area then send the email.

Comment: I have found this tutorial for using custom fonts in Mailchimp: https://ericlbarnes.com/2015/03/06/mailchimp-fonts/

I have not tested it.