# Webfonts are not rendering on Gmail app, but are rendering on Gmail Web App

Tags: html, css, gmail, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm trying to use a **"Comic Sans MS"** font, this font loads perfectly in the gmail web app, but when it comes to gmail app, it does not render in the gmail or does not load the font, it just displays a regular font, i surfed all the posts on internet and Stackoverflow but could not figure out where is my code going wrong.

Below is the code i'm using, not sure where am i going wrong! It would be great, if someone could let me know what mistake i'm doing ans where.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html  style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\">
            <head>
            <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\" />
            <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />
            <title>Email Verification</title>
            <style type=\"text/css\">
            img {
            max-width: 100%;
            }
            body {
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; width: 100% !important; height: 100%; line-height: 1.6em;
            }
            body {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            }
            @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
              body {
                padding: 0 !important;
              }
              h1 {
                font-weight: 800 !important; margin: 20px 0 5px !important;
              }
              h2 {
                font-weight: 800 !important; margin: 20px 0 5px !important;
              }
              h3 {
                font-weight: 800 !important; margin: 20px 0 5px !important;
              }
              h4 {
                font-weight: 800 !important; margin: 20px 0 5px !important;
              }
              h1 {
                font-size: 22px !important;
              }
              h2 {
                font-size: 18px !important;
              }
              h3 {
                font-size: 16px !important;
              }
              .container {
                padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important;
              }
              .content {
                padding: 0 !important;
              }
              .content-wrap {
                padding: 10px !important;
              }
              .invoice {
                width: 100% !important;
              }
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/EmailMessage\" style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; width: 100% !important; height: 100%; line-height: 1.6em; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0;\" bgcolor=\"#f6f6f6\">
            <table class=\"body-wrap\" style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; width: 100%; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0;\" bgcolor=\"#f6f6f6\"><tr style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\"><td style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0;\" valign=\"top\"></td>
                <td class=\"container\" width=\"600\" style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; display: block !important; max-width: 600px !important; clear: both !important; margin: 0 auto;\" valign=\"top\">
                  <div class=\"content\" style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; max-width: 600px; display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px;\">
                    <table class=\"main\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; border-radius: 3px; background-color: #fff; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;\" bgcolor=\"#fff\"><tr style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\">
                      </tr><tr style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\"><td class=\"content-wrap\" style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 20px;\" valign=\"top\">
                          <table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\"><tr style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\"><td class=\"content-block\" style=\"font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',cursive,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;\" valign=\"top\">
                                Hi,
                                <br /><br />
                                Please verify your email address by clicking the link below.
                                <br /><br />
                                <a href=\"$url\">$url</a>
                                <br /><br />
                                If the above URL does not work try copying and pasting it into your browser.<br /><br />
                                If you still encounter any problem, please contact us at <a href=\"mailto:support@xyz.com\">support@xyz.com</a>
                                <br /><br />
                                Thank You,<br />
                                The XYZTeam
                              </td>
                            </tr></table></td>
                      </tr></table>
                </td>
              </tr></table></body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly mail apps wont support fonts. The font that you have used might be installed in your windows/mac system. So, when you open the mail in browser it will render properly with the font you have used. In mobiles it will be default fonts instead of the font you used.

Please refer [Gmail not showing correct font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747848/gmail-not-showing-correct-font)

Comment: I've done the inline styling as well to the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags, still it does not show it.

Comment: Yes, It wont work as gmail app wont render the font. It will support only few default fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail App is ungrateful when it comes to the email templates.
There is a ton of things that the Gmail app doesn't handle.